# Gulp 4 - single task for multiple paths

Tags: gulp

I am working on a Gulp file for WordPress development. I create Themes & Plugins so require my Gulpfile to watch for sass changes for both.

I currently have 2 paths defined and a separate Gulp task for plugins & themes, however I would like to try and improve this by having a single Sass task that can use either path.

```
// File paths
const files = { 
    themeScssPath: 'htdocs/wp-content/themes/**/assets/src/scss/**/*.scss',
    pluginScssPath: 'htdocs/wp-content/plugins/jhdev-*/assets/src/scss/**/*.scss',
}

// Theme Sass: compiles Theme style.scss file into style.css
function themeScssTask(){    
    return src(files.themeScssPath, {base: "./"})
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) // initialize sourcemaps first
        .pipe(sass()) // compile SCSS to CSS
        .pipe(postcss([ autoprefixer(), cssnano() ])) // PostCSS plugins
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.')) // write sourcemaps file in current directory
        .pipe(rename(function (path) {
            path.dirname += "/../../dist";
          }))
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: ".min" }))
        .pipe(dest('./'))
}

// Plugin Sass: compiles Theme style.scss file into style.css
function pluginScssTask(){    
    return src(files.pluginScssPath, {base: "./"})
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) // initialize sourcemaps first
        .pipe(sass()) // compile SCSS to CSS
        .pipe(postcss([ autoprefixer(), cssnano() ])) // PostCSS plugins
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.')) // write sourcemaps file in current directory
        .pipe(rename(function (path) {
            path.dirname += "/../../dist";
          }))
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: ".min" }))
        .pipe(dest('./'))
}

// Watch task: watch SCSS and JS files for changes
function watchTask(){
    watch([files.themeScssPath, files.pluginScssPath], 
        parallel(themeScssTask, pluginScssTask));    
}

exports.default = series(
    parallel(themeScssTask, pluginScssTask), 
    watchTask
);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
// File paths
const files = [
    'htdocs/wp-content/themes/**/assets/src/scss/**/*.scss',
    'htdocs/wp-content/plugins/jhdev-*/assets/src/scss/**/*.scss'
];

// Sass: compiles *.scss file into *.css
function scssTask(){    
    return src(files, {base: "./"})
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) // initialize sourcemaps first
        .pipe(sass()) // compile SCSS to CSS
        .pipe(postcss([ autoprefixer(), cssnano() ])) // PostCSS plugins
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.')) // write sourcemaps file in current directory
        .pipe(rename(function (path) {
            path.dirname += "/../../dist";
          }))
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: ".min" }))
        .pipe(dest('./'))
}

// Watch task: watch SCSS and JS files for changes
function watchTask(){
    watch(files, scssTask);
}

exports.default = series(
    scssTask, 
    watchTask
);
```